# How to deploy a ServiceStack developed application in VS 2013 onto a Ubuntu 12.4 Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, ubuntu, mono

I arrived at the below mentioned question

[Host ServiceStack, MVC3 or MVC4 on mono or windows and what is the state of mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556081/host-servicestack-mvc3-or-mvc4-on-mono-or-windows-and-what-is-the-state-of-mono/12556414#12556414?newreg=28f47793527745119feff5af6154d438)

The answer was that: 
"ServiceStack.net has always run on Linux/Mono" which is not what I want to know:

I would like to know HOW to deploy it.   There is loads of examples on how to create your service stack application, but not much on how to deploy it.

My situation is as follows:   I have downloaded MS VS 2013 (The express version for web).

I would like to write a service stack service in it (have achieved that already with the helloworld examples on the web) and then deploy this code to a Ubuntu server 12.4, running mono on Apache.

Please would anyone explain how to do that (step-wise please).  Any pointers to pit falls would be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a documentation how to run ServiceStack on mono https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Mono

By the way, if you're going to change apache to nginx as your front-end it's better to use [HyperFastCgi](https://github.com/xplicit/HyperFastCgi) instead of mono-server-fastcgi. HyperFastCgi does not leak memory and runs much faster.

The issues with standard mono-server-fastcgi are described [here](http://forcedtoadmin.blogspot.ru/2013/11/servicestack-performance-in-mono-p2.html)

To install HyperFastCgi on mono machine, you should get the sources and compile them:

```
git clone https://github.com/xplicit/HyperFastCgi.git
cd HyperFastCgi
#if you have got mono installed not in /usr/bin/mono, change the prefix
#to the directory, where mono is located (without 'bin' part)
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip - will definitely go that route.  I am still unsure once I have my "Hello world" example running nicely on the debug mode on my computer (compiling .Net 4.5 - how I get it ready to run on HyperfastCGI?   

Do I have to recompile this application with mono for instance and how exactly do I do that from visual studio 2013?

Many thanks

Comment: You don't have to recompile your application. For HyperFastCgi your should compile it on your mono instance. This is pretty simple, I added commands to the answer.