# Is there a ServiceStack, Mono, Ubuntu stack build on apt-get or cloud version?

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, servicestack, lamp

Is there a LAMP version with ServiceStack for easy peasy deployment on latest Ubuntu builds?

Or even a cloud version of ServiceStack as I dont want to spend my time fussing over settings but building the end product.

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStack itself is not available through apt-get, instead it can be downloaded and used a project dependency / library in your code. See the [download](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack#download) details (there's a way to get the libraries without NuGet there as well).

Following the description in [this](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-ServiceStack-in-Fastcgi-hosted-on-nginx#install-prerequisites) ServiceStack wiki page:

```
sudo apt-get install mono
sudo apt-get install mono-fastcgi-server4
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Note that nginx is not essential for running a SS powered web app. You could actually start off with the [self-hosting](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Self-hosting) option to get a feel for SS and choose between the different options. In other words, you can `sudo apt-get install mono` followed by downloading SS libraries and you're good to go.

You should probably also bookmark [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188356/what-is-the-best-way-to-run-servicestack-on-linux-mono/12188358#12188358) SO question & answer as a good resource. No idea why it's closed.

Good luck!