# Configuring multiple sites on a single dedicated server

Tags: python, django

I have a set of sites written on Python (Django). At one site comes to 10 times more traffic than others. All are worked on one dedicated server. Why biggest site works more slowly then other?

Configuration: Ubuntu 12.04, Apache2, Django 1.3.1 (running through mod_wsgi), PostgreSQL 9.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `dpkg --get-selections | grep mpm` show that you are using `apache2-mpm-worker` or `apache2-mpm-prefork`? I use **`apache2-mpm-worker`** and have also tuned the `apache2.conf` to better allocate processes/threads. The `prefork` worker is not ideal for Python/WSGI (though this is just my opinion).

`patrick@romulus:~$ sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-worker`

---

`patrick@romulus:~$ sudo vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadLimit: ThreadsPerChild can be changed to this maximum value during a
#              graceful restart. ThreadLimit can only be changed by stopping
#              and starting Apache.
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

---

Then, in your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site.conf` configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

# ...

# The following installs the Django WSGI app
    WSGIDaemonProcess www.site.io threads=20 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup www.site.io
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/site.io/public/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

---

I believe this tuning may improve your site; however, **be sure to copy your `apache2.conf` and `site.conf` before making any changes** so you can revert if site performance becomes worse.

`patrick@romulus:~$ sudo cp /etc/apache2/apache2.conf ~/apache2.conf.bak`
`patrick@romulus:~$ sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/site.conf ~/site.conf.bak`

Comment: You can try to connect over UNIX socket instead of TCP to access db. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12101626/1545769

Answer (score 0):

No where near enough information, we would need a really good crystal ball to be able to even guess. Go watch:

- http://lanyrd.com/2012/pycon/spcdg/
- http://lanyrd.com/2013/pycon/scdyzk/

That may at least give you a starting point as to what you can do to work out what the issue is.