# How to configure ngnix for rails port?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, puma

Hello this is my first time deploying rails app to a ubuntu server so after I configured nginx and got the `"welcome to nginx page"` at a certain IP ... and when I start rails application I must enter the port in the IP address for example `165.217.84.11:3000` in order to access rails so how to make rails run default when I run only this IP `165.217.84.11`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the redirection from the 80 port (wich is the default) to the 3000 like this:

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    client_max_body_size 10m;
    sendfile on;

    upstream rails {
        server 165.217.84.11:3000;
    }


    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {    
            proxy_pass         http://rails-app;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Ssl off;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }

}
```

So, when you access 165.217.84.11 in the browser you should see your rails project.

Comment: thanks for your answer it almost works but there is a problem :  it runs on `165.217.84.11.COM/index` so how can i get rid of this `.com` ( both `upstream rails` and `proxy_pass` are set to `165.217.84.11:3000` ( I don't yet have a domain name )

Answer (score 0):

In general you have to setup your nginx to use puma socket file and then it will access the website using socket file instead of using TCP port (`:3000` by the default).

Here is a nice tutorial: [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/257479/2039726) is a short explanation why you should use sockets.